# Unable to start the rails server after installing gem for twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A VERY HAPPY AND PROSPEROUS NEW YEAR TO ALL.

I have started learning ROR and trying to create my first application with it. I am trying to use Twitter bootstrap gem. After bundle install, when i am trying to run the rails server command i am getting this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:3:in `require': /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
```

Can somebody please guide me what i am missing here ?

here is the stack trace of the same:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:3:in `require': /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
    I18n.t name, scope: scope
                       ^
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:3
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb:4:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb:4
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /var/www/ahex_connect/config/application.rb:7
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Comment: You will need to add the complete stack trace in here

Comment: Thanks ! I have edited my question to add the stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Ruby 1.8 while the syntax on line #33 (inside the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem) is from Ruby 1.9. They already fixed this to make it compatible on `master`. So possible solutions:

1. Upgrade your Ruby version to 1.9.
2. Use git version of the gem. Put this to Gemfile (modify the existing line) and run `bundle install`

   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'

Comment: Thanks first i tried step 2 but then i was getting some errors ... so i upgraded the ruby version ...... its working now